# Redirect all url request to one handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In a Google App Engine application with google webapp framework, how do I redirect every request to one handler?

Check this code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can i change the `application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],                    debug=True)` line to redirect all the requests instead only the `/`. I tried and `*` and `/*` and it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', MainPage)], ...`